# Use a wildcard in a google places api search

Tags: java, android, user-interface, google-places-api

I am using google places web api for searching for places with urls that look like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=somequery&...
```

how can I pass a wildcarded query to places? For example, if I search for "bakery" I get all places that have the word bakery in their name, but if I search for "bak" or "bak*" I get absolutely nothing. I want the search to return results even if only a part of the name matches the pattern. Is this possible?

Edit: the exact query looks like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=29.0640279%2C26.7747916&types=cafe%7Crestaurant&query=bake&radius=50000&key=some_key

Comment: Hav you tried to use %25 instead of asterisk (UrlEncoded % char)? Also, how does your query look like exactly?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried but I still get zero results. I'm looking at possibly solving this by moving over to the autocomplete api instead if it isn't possible to use wildcards here.

Comment: why not use google place autocomplete API https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: I remember that I tried to use the android api and there was a problem with the types that it supported (vs the web api). However, the same question essentially arises - does the android api support wildcards?